# Grouping of similar data from json and print it into table using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have the JSON file and I am getting the JSON data using Angular.js but I want the result according to table which is shown below.

There is the my HTML code and my JavaScript code using Angular I am fetching the JSON data:

[image]

This is my JSON file:

[image]

Comment: It is better to insert code snippets instead of the images. And what is the question and what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the array of all the groups in your controller and then use [`ngRepeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) to render [`tbody`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_tbody.asp) tags for the groups. Then in nested `ng-repeat` you can iterate through the items using custom `getGroupedItems` [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter):

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.tableData = [
      {
        "name":"Pro-1",
        "histology":"CLL",
        "id":"1"
      },
      {
        "name":"Pro-2",
        "histology":"CLL",
        "id":"2"
      },
      {
        "name":"Pro-3",
        "histology":"DLBCL",
        "id":"30"
      },
      {
        "name":"Pro-4",
        "histology":"CLL",
        "id":"55"
      },
      {
        "name":"Pro-5",
        "histology":"MCL",
        "id":"1255"
      },
      {
        "name":"Pro-4",
        "histology":"DLBCL",
        "id":"55"
      },
    ];
    
    $scope.getGroups = function (data, prop) {
      var groupsArray = [];
      angular.forEach(data, function (item, idx) {
          if (groupsArray.indexOf(item[prop]) == -1) {
              groupsArray.push(item[prop]);
          }
      });
      return groupsArray;
  };
})
.filter('getGroupedItems', function(){
    return function(items, prop, value){       
       return items.filter(function(element, index, array) {
        return element[prop] === value;
       });        
    }        
})
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table thead {
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

table tbody {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  border-collapse: separate;
}

table td {
  padding: 5px;
}

table td.group-col {
  vertical-align: top;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ctrl"> 
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Id</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody ng-repeat="group in getGroups(tableData, 'histology') track by $index">
    <tr ng-repeat="(ind, item) in (groupedItems = (tableData | getGroupedItems:'histology':group)) track by item.id">
     <td class="group-col" ng-if="ind == 0" rowspan="{{::groupedItems.length}}">{{::group}}</td>
     <td>{{item.name}}</td>
     <td>{{item.id}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: @ns093 was this helpful to you?